# Mount specific folder in bucket using s3fs in /etc/fstab

Tags: fstab, s3fs

Using S3FS, a specific folder in a bucket can be mounted using `s3fs bucket:/path/to/folder <mountpoint>`. This works fine for me.

I'd like to mount in the same way using an entry in `/etc/fstab`, but can't figure out how to specify the path to the folder. Mounting the entire bucket works just fine:
`bucket       local_path  fuse.s3fs       _netdev,allow_other,passwd_file=/etc/password-s3fs 0 0`

However, specifying the folder path results in the bucket being unrecognized:
`bucket:/folder       local_path  fuse.s3fs       _netdev,allow_other,passwd_file=/etc/password-s3fs 0 0`

`s3fs_check_service(3711): bucket not found - result of checking service.`

Is there a different way of specifying a path to a folder?

Answer (score 1):

Does the following format work:

```
s3fs#bucket:/folder
```

Note that this may require a directory object to exist, e.g., created via s3fs.